# failed to call webhook: Post[https://istiod.istio-system.svc:443/validate?timeout=30s] validate?timeout=30s

Tags: webhooks, istio, istio-gateway, istio-sidecar

I am unable to create virtual service or a serviceaccount in my GKE environment. My current istio version is istio-1.16.2.

kubectl apply -f vs.yml
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating “vs.yml”: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook “validation.istio.io”: failed to call webhook: Post “https://istiod.istio-system.svc:443/validate?timeout=30s”: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

This is the error I am facing. Need an expert opinion on this.

Issue in creation of virtual service or any serviceaccount that needs validations webhooks

Comment: Checking istiod pod logs under istio-system namespace will give clue